# Ubuntu 12.04 Depends: postgresql-9.1-postgis

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, package-management, postgresql

I am installing LocalWiki on a Virtual Machine hosted by 1&1.com It is Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run `sudo apt-get install localwiki` as instructed by http://localwiki.org/install/,

I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
localwiki : Depends: postgresql-9.1-postgis but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried on my own to install `postgresql` but I ended up making things worse. I just did a clean install on 12.04 and I was wondering if someone here could assist me further.

Thanks.

**edit**: I even ran `sudo apt-get install postgresql` successfully and I still get the same error.
**edit**: I also want to point out that I think it may be something with my server. It says that 1&1 installs the OS with minimal OS. When I tried the instructions of localwiki on a VM on my local machine with 12.04, they worked perfectly. So I probably need to update something on my VM I am renting from 1and1?
**edit**: I downgraded to 9.1.5, since in another questions on here that seemed to work. It didn't work for me :(

Comment: Please try to incorporate edits properly into the body of your question by rewriting the relevant part of the question as opposed to adding them at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Install the missing package. It will pull in postgres-9.1 (not the other way around):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis localwiki
```

Comment: That still did not work. I get the same error

Comment: @PolarisUser Please include in your question the full output of `apt-get update; apt-get install postgres-9.1-postgis`